# Cuda failed to run on blocks but ok on grids

Tags: cuda

Here is part of my cuda code from cs344:
It is a task to convert a picture in rgb to gray.
The code runs ok now.
But when I use the code in the comments. It fails.

```
__global__
void rgba_to_greyscale(const uchar4* const rgbaImage,
                       unsigned char* const greyImage,
                       int numRows, int numCols)
{
  //int x = threadIdx.x ;
  //int y = threadIdx.y ;      
  int x = blockIdx.x ;
  int y = blockIdx.y ;

  if (x<numCols && y<numRows)
  {
    uchar4 rgba = rgbaImage[y*numCols+x] ;
    float channelSum = .299f * rgba.x + .587f * rgba.y + .114f * rgba.z;
    greyImage[y*numCols+x] = channelSum;
  }
}    


void your_rgba_to_greyscale(const uchar4 * const h_rgbaImage, 
                            uchar4 * const d_rgbaImage, unsigned char* const d_greyImage, 
                            size_t numRows, size_t numCols)
{
  // const dim3 blockSize(numCols,numRows , 1);  //TODO
  // const dim3 gridSize( 1, 1, 1);  //TODO
  const dim3 blockSize(1,1 , 1);  //TODO
  const dim3 gridSize( numCols,numRows , 1);  //TODO
  std::cout << numCols << " " << numRows << std::endl ; // numCols=557 numRows=313
  rgba_to_greyscale<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_rgbaImage, d_greyImage, numRows, numCols);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize(); 
  checkCudaErrors(cudaGetLastError());
}
```

The code fails to run when I use the commented ones, with errors:

```
CUDA error at: /home/yc/cuda_prj/cs344_bak/Problem Sets/Problem Set 1/student_func.cu:90
invalid configuration argument cudaGetLastError()
```

Here is my deviceQuery report:

```
Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "GeForce GTX 1080"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          8.0 / 8.0
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    6.1
  Total amount of global memory:                 8110 MBytes (8504279040 bytes)
  (20) Multiprocessors, (128) CUDA Cores/MP:     2560 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            1823 MHz (1.82 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             5005 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              256-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 2097152 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(131072), 2D=(131072, 65536), 3D=(16384, 16384, 16384)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(32768), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(32768, 32768), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 65536
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 2 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 1 / 0
Compute Mode:
   < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

  deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 8.0, CUDA Runtime Version = 8.0, NumDevs = 1, Device0 = GeForce GTX 1080
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: threadblocks in CUDA are limited to 1024 threads in total.  When you use the commented code you are exceeding this somehow.  I can't tell you how exactly because I don't know what numrows and numcols are.  On SO, when you're asking for help on a code that doesn't work, you are supposed to provide a *complete* example, a [mcve].  Regarding the limit on threads per block, this is documented in CUDA (just look at your deviceQuery output!) and covered in many many many many questions here on SO If you look around.

Comment: the total threads per block is the product of the dimensions.  If your dimensions are `numCols=557 numRows=313` then the product of those is over 150,000.  The limit on the total threads per block on your device is 1024 and it is in the deviceQuery output here: `Maximum number of threads per block:           1024`

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer, Robert. I will pay attention to what you have mentioned in the first answer.

Answer (score 1):

Robert posts the answer that solves the problem:

> The total threads per block is the product of the dimensions. If your dimensions are numCols=557 numRows=313 then the product of those is over 150,000. The limit on the total threads per block on your device is 1024 and it is in the deviceQuery output here: Maximum number of threads per block: 1024